# Maximum weighted matching on a tripartite 3-uniform hypergraph

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

There are polynomial algorithms for finding a maximum weighted matching on a bipartite graph, e.g. the hungarian algorithm. Is there such an algorithm for a tripartite 3-uniform hypergraph? What about a k-partite k-uniform hypergraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this is called [3-dimensional matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching), and it's known to be an NP-hard problem. So the answer is no.